# grep multiple strings and store/print next line values in a variable

Tags: xml, awk, grep

I am trying to grep multiple strings from pom.xml file... for eg below are the contents of the xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.bluesoft.muleesb</groupId>
    <artifactId>Magellan23888Adapter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>mule-application</packaging>

    <name>Magellan23888Adapter</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <app.runtime>4.3.0</app.runtime>
        <mule.maven.plugin.version>3.3.5</mule.maven.plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${mule.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <sharedLibraries>
                        <sharedLibrary>
                            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
                            <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.allclient</artifactId>
                        </sharedLibrary>
                    </sharedLibraries>
                    <classifier>mule-application</classifier>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>releases</id>
            <name>bluesoft releases</name>
            <url>http://nexus.bluesoft.com/repository/releases</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <name>bluesoft snapshots</name>
            <url>http://nexus.bluesoft.com/repository/snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-x12-connector</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.2</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-objectstore-connector</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.7</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.allclient</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-json-module</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-http-connector</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-file-connector</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-ibm-mq-connector</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.3</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-sftp-connector</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-secure-configuration-property-module</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-email-connector</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>bluesoft-nexus</id>
            <name>bluesoft Nexus</name>
            <url>https://nexus.bluesoft.com/content/groups/public</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>bluesoft-nexus-plugins</id>
            <name>bluesoft Nexus</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>https://nexus.bluesoft.com/content/groups/public</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

I am trying to run the below command to get the above output from the file

```bash
grep -i -A3 'com.mulesoft.connectors\|org.mule.connectors' pom.xml
```

I want to print the values as below when the above criteria matches, for eg

I am trying to capture all the matched patterns from my below command

```bash
grep -i -A3 'com.mulesoft.connectors\|org.mule.connectors' pom.xml
```

and from this command i am trying to get artifactId and version

expected output:

```
artifactId value,version
------------------------
mule-ibm-mq-connector,1.8.3
mule-file-connector,1.5.2
mule-salesforce-connector,10.8.1
mule-email-connector,1.1.8
mule-connector,1.4.1
```

Comment: obligatory https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1032785

Comment: This is something that would be readily written as an XSLT template. Look at [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) as an example of a tool that will write those templates for you (after they're built, you can run them with xmlproc, which is preinstalled pretty much everywhere). Of course, you can also just tell xmlstarlet to just output the data you want instead of having it write the template explicitly.

Comment: Please show valid XML.

Comment: (err, when I said "xmlproc" above that should have been "xsltproc")

Comment: @jordanm I suggest that you *not* post that answer, because chances are that OP won't understand it.  You and I may laugh at it because we understand what it's saying, but rookies looking for help won't get it.  Instead, point to a something that actually explains the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An XML parser like `xmllint` suites this task better but you cannot install a new tool for some reason you may consider this `grep | gnu-awk` solution:

```bash
grep -i -A3 'com\.mulesoft\.connectors\|org\.mule\.connectors' pom.xml |
awk -v RS='--' -v OFS=, 'BEGIN {print "artifactId value,version"} 
{gsub(/<\/?[^>]+>/, ""); print $2, $3}'

artifactId value,version
mule-x12-connector,2.6.2
mule-objectstore-connector,1.1.7
mule-http-connector,1.5.6
mule-file-connector,1.3.3
mule-ibm-mq-connector,1.6.3
mule-sftp-connector,1.4.0
mule-email-connector,1.4.1
```

Comment: I tried both the solutions but non is working @anubhava

Comment: I want to capture all from my below command

grep -i -A3 'com.mulesoft.connectors\|org.mule.connectors' pom.xml

from this command i am trying to get artifactId and version

Comment: i edited my question and expected output as well in my post

Comment: your solution works but the problem is it is also printing the values from other groupId tags, apart from the two that i am looking for

Comment: solution worked. I really appreciate taking time and helping me with the solution. Is there any way i can also append the file name on each line? i tried to pass the variable but its not working

Comment: I tried to pass variable but it is not working

Comment: What are you trying to pass? Are you expanding your problem or it is part of the question's expected output?

Comment: It is not part of the question, I was just trying to print as below <br><br>

artifactId value,version,filename
mule-x12-connector,2.6.2,pom.xml

Comment: ok try: `fn='pom.xml'; grep -i -A3 'com\.mulesoft\.connectors\|org\.mule\.connectors' "$fn" | awk -v fn="$fn" -v RS='--' -v OFS=, 'BEGIN {print "artifactId value,version,filename"} {gsub(/<\/?[^>]+>/, ""); print $2, $3, fn}'`

Comment: Thank you. Looks like I was trying the same but looks like there was a typo and parenthesis was missing at the end.

Comment: how can i ignore comments with in xml file? for eg some of my xml files has commented xml tags something like this             

<!--             <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId> -->

 
and some has the comments ended at the end of the block of xml tags

Comment: Praveen you need to post a new question for new requirements. Comment section is for discussion on current problem and solution

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following Single `awk` code(Not using `grep` here and within single `awk` itself handling the matches, conditions and printing values as per requirement). Written and tested in GNU `awk` and it uses GNU `awk'` `match` function's creating arrays from capturing group values(which are getting created by regex used in solution).

Here is the [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1iwUII/1) for used regex for understanding purposes, regex creates 3 capturing groups out of which 1st one is getting used for checking condition purposes and rest 2 are getting printed if condition of 1st capturing groups is meeting the OP's condition.

```bash
awk -v RS="^$" '
{
  while(match($0,/<groupId>([^<]*)<\/groupId>\n[[:space:]]*<artifactId>([^<]*)\
<\/artifactId>\n[[:space:]]*<version>([^<]*)<\/version>/,arr)){
    if(arr[1]=="com.mulesoft.connectors" || arr[1]=="org.mule.connectors"){
      if(++count==1){
         print "artifactId value,version"
      }
      print arr[2]","arr[3]
    }
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: @Praveen Kumar, Good that you have accepted an answer. You could check other answers also(once you get time) and reply them back how they went, by doing this it may help future users, cheers.

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> echo "${input_data}" | 
>
> mawk NF=NF FS='<[/]artifactId>[^>]+>'     OFS=',' \
>          RS='(<[/]version>\n[^\n]+\n+)?([^\n]+\n+[ \t]+<artifactId>)?'
> ```

```
mule-ibm-mq-connector,1.8.3
mule-file-connector,1.5.2
mule-salesforce-connector,10.8.1
mule-email-connector,1.1.8
mule-connector,1.4.1
```

the header rows should be trivial